# Matplotlib-Latex Rendering Issue

Tags: matplotlib, latex, windows-11, ubuntu-22.04

I have upgraded Ubuntu to 22.04 and my all matplotlib rendering with latex started having problem.
I am trying to render Latex text as x and y labels

`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams.update({
        "text.usetex": True,
        "font.family": "Helvetica"
})
plt.rcParams.update({
        "text.usetex": True,
        "font.family": "Helvetica"
    })
plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble']         = [
                                                r"\usepackage{textgreek}",
                                                r"\usepackage{siunitx}",
                                                r"\usepackage{bm}",
                                                r"\usepackage{isomath}",
                                                r"\usepackage{amsmath}",
                                                r"\usepackage{commath}"    ]


# Example data
t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0 + 0.01, 0.01)
s = np.cos(4 * np.pi * t) + 2

plt.plot(t, s)

plt.xlabel(r'$\textbf{time}$')
plt.ylabel(r'$\boldsymbol{d}$')   # --> problem is here

plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.8)

plt.savefig('tex_demo.png')
```

`

I have tried installing all necessary packages as suggested by people in similar threads, but nothing seems to work.

I have tried installing all necessary packages as suggested by people in similar threads, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: It does not render r"/boldsymbol{d}" RuntimeError: latex was not able to process the following string:
b'$\\\\boldsymbol{d}$'